# Read only vs NonRestrict Read Write in Cache Concurrency in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, second-level-cache

I am a beginner in Hibernate and came across these concepts in JPA second level cache concurrency strategy:

```
Read-Only: Used when the cache is never updated. Data like names of countries etc are suitable candidate

Non-Strict Read-Write: Data that is rarely updated.
```

I am confused as to what exactly is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `read-only` for cache entries that are queried once, usually during the startup of an application or upon the first request and it is certain that the result loaded will never change during the lifetime of the application. Like in the description the list of countries is a good example.

For the `Non-Strict Read-Write`, you use this option when an update to the cached result may change occasionally.

For example the days of the week that a shop is opened. This, in general, does not change but due to some renovation the next Sunday may be closed and that would cause an update to the cache.

This enforces additional checks and synchronization on the persistence provider thus its performance is not the highest (like in `read-only`).

You need to judge whether it is more relevant to use `read-only` whenever possible and restart the server when a rare change of the dictionaries occur or implement the `Non-Strict Read-Write` and deal with a bit slower performance but without the need of restarting the server every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about the frequency per-se; it's about optimizations that the cache implementation can do. When the level is set to `read-only` the engine knows that your app is not going to update the entity/collection, and can avoid some locking etc. The `non-strict read-write` level is not defined in detail, however it lets the implementation do another kind of optimizations, possibly with reduced consistency. In regular `read-write` mode the cache tries to stay in exact sync with database; in `non-strict` mode it can open a brief window when the cache would provide stale data (something that is not in DB anymore). The benefit is possibly an increase in performance.

If your updates are infrequent there is a low chance that something will go wrong (e.g. updates to an entity will clash) and that's why you could decide to take such risk.